# How to use Wikidata API to get ISO 3166-1 country codes?

Tags: javascript, wikidata, wikidata-api

I have been looking for examples online but can't find any for getting ISO 3166-1 country codes using [the Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q25275).

It's [mentioned here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Data_access#SPARQL_endpoints) that one can do `https://query.wikidata.org/sparql` or `https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/ldf`, but I don't really know the difference. Also, I'm used to using APIs that return JSON, which it seems like neither of these two endpoints are. Is there a way to get JSON?

Overall, just wondering how to do this properly since examples are few and far between (or none at all).

Comment: Would be nice if the person that downvoted could state what's wrong with the question so I can modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Use [this SPARQL query](https://w.wiki/WQS). It get the list of countries that has ISO 36 code value. After entering the previous URL, You can click  Download button to download the response to JSON, CSV...etc.

```
#Find ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country codes
SELECT ?country ?countryLabel ?code
WHERE
{
    ?country wdt:P297 ?code .
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en" }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wikidata's API is not meant to be used for that kind of queries on the fly. You would need to get all items that have the property `P297` (ISO 3166) which will give you the list of countries and then fetch each country with all it's claims just to get the ISO 3166 value.

Instead, why not have a copy of the codes on your server, or even fetch it from a clean source meant for that, like this one: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;alpha2Code